# Busqueda en fragment que contiene elementos ListView

Tags: android, activity, fragment, búsquedas

Tengo un fragment llamado Alabanzas el cual contiene elementos ListView.
Deseo implementar una barra de busqueda de los elementos existentes en el ListView pero no se como hacerlo, hasta ahora he intentado implementar con el searchView pero no lo logro.
Estas son mis clases
Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Adaptador miadaptador;
    ListView listaDatos;
    ArrayList<Datos> Lista= new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        CargarFragmento(new Alabanza());
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
        miadaptador = new Adaptador(getApplicationContext(),Lista);

//        listaDatos.setAdapter(miadaptador);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search,menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
        SearchView searchView= (SearchView)item.getActionView();



        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                miadaptador.getFilter().filter(s);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            CargarFragmento(new Alabanza());
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
           CargarFragmento(new Temas());
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    private void CargarFragmento(Fragment fragmento){
        FragmentManager Manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedorFragmento, fragmento).commit();

    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Clase Alabanza

```
public class Alabanza extends Fragment {


    ListView listaDatos;
    ArrayList<Datos> Lista= new ArrayList<>();

    Adaptador miadaptador;


    public ArrayList<Datos> getLista() {
        return Lista;
    }

    public void setLista(ArrayList<Datos> lista) {
        Lista = lista;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alabanza, container, false);

        listaDatos = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lstDatos);

        Lista.add(new Datos(1,"A la Diestra de Dios"));
        Lista.add(new Datos(2,"A solas al Huerto"));
        Lista.add(new Datos(3,"A ti Señor"));
        Lista.add(new Datos(4,"A veces me pregunto"));
        Lista.add(new Datos(5,"Al divino Salvador"));
        Lista.add(new Datos(6,"Al Mundo Paz"));
        Lista.add(new Datos(7,"Alabado el gran manantial"));
        Lista.add(new Datos(8,"Alabanzas a Dios dad"));
        Lista.add(new Datos(9,"Aleluya Amen"));
        Lista.add(new Datos(10,"Aleluya oh Creador"));



        miadaptador = new Adaptador(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),Lista);
        listaDatos.setAdapter(miadaptador);

        //Agregamos escuchador
        listaDatos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Datos obj=(Datos) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                //Creamos el paso hacia la nueva activity
                Intent paso=new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), DetalleActivity.class);
                paso.putExtra("objeto", (Serializable) obj); // Serializamos el traspaso del objeto
                //Realiza el traspaso a la otra activity
                startActivity(paso);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

alabanzas.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragmentos.Alabanza"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstDatos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Y finalmente la clase Adaptador

```
public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    Context contexto;
    ArrayList<Datos> ListaObjetos;
    ArrayList<Datos> mStringFilterList;
    ValueFilter valueFilter;

    public Adaptador(Context contexto, ArrayList<Datos> listaObjetos) {
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.ListaObjetos = listaObjetos;
        mStringFilterList=listaObjetos;
    }

    /*
    Retorna cantidad de elementos de la vista
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.ListaObjetos.size();
    }

    /*
        Retorna objeto puntual de la posicion que indico
         */
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return this.ListaObjetos.get(i);
    }

    /*
    Retorna Id del objeto puntual de la posicion que indico
     */
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return this.ListaObjetos.get(i).getId();
    }

    /*
    Se ejecuta en cada secuencia de cada hito de la listview
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View vista = view;

        //Inyectamos el layout definido dentro de la vista del ListView
        LayoutInflater inflate = LayoutInflater.from(contexto);
        vista = inflate.inflate(R.layout.itemlistview, null);

        //Referenciamos el titulo
        TextView titulo = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tw_titulo);
        titulo.setText(ListaObjetos.get(i).getTitulo().toString());
        return vista;
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }

    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Datos> filterList = new ArrayList<Datos>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                    if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getTitulo().toUpperCase())
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                        Datos data = new Datos(mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getId(), mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getTitulo());

                        filterList.add(data);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
                results.values = mStringFilterList;
            }
            return results;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            ListaObjetos = (ArrayList<Datos>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Espero de su ayuda... estoy  desesperado :c

Comment: relice una pregunta parecida y se quedo en el olvido supongo que tu error es que no encuentra el searchView verdad? Mira lo que te puedo poner es como hacerlo pero no en el toolbar sino en el top de tu listView dime si te lo pongo

Comment: Claro, igual me sirve... Gracias de antemano

Comment: revisa que mañana te lo dejo ok disculpa por no poder hacerlo hoy

Answer (score 0):

Mira este es el codigo para declarar el serchView en el xml de tu activity

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Este es el codigo para utilizarlo

Esto es en el onCreate

```
    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);

    // Sets the default or resting state of the search field. If true, a single search icon is shown by default and
    // expands to show the text field and other buttons when pressed. Also, if the default state is iconified, then it
    // collapses to that state when the close button is pressed. Changes to this property will take effect immediately.
    // The default value is true. Disculpa lo copie asi porque no estaba para traducirlo si quieres lo traduzco.
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

    search(searchView);

 private void search(SearchView searchView) {

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            if(newText.length() == 0)
            {
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                listViewFind.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return false;
            }

            filteredModelList = filter(allItems, newText);

            if (filteredModelList.size() > 0)
            {
                listViewFind.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long id) {
                         //aquí pones lo que quieras
                        }
                        });
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                        builder.create().show();
                    }
                });
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                //aquí pones un toast diciendo que no se encontraron resultados
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}

 private List<Note> filter(List<Note> Notes, String query) {

    query = query.toLowerCase();

    filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Note note : Notes) {
        final String text = note.getEntity().toLowerCase();
        final String number = note.getDescription().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(note);
        }
        else if(number.contains(query))
        {
            filteredModelList.add(note);
        }
    }

    // arraylist in your adapter
    //noteRealmResultsQuery = realm.where(Note.class).contains("description", query).findAll();
    noteAdapterFind = new FindAdapterNote(this, filteredModelList, R.layout.list_find_note);
    listViewFind.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    listViewFind.setAdapter(noteAdapterFind);
    noteAdapterFind.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return filteredModelList;
}
```

Espero que te funcione, Note es creado por mi tienes que sustituirlo ok. Cualquier duda comenta ok. Recuerda que lo que estoy haciendo es ponerte lo que hice como ejemplo.